# How do I parse this JSON in swift? Object starting with a number

Tags: json, swift, object, parsing, numbers

So I'm able to parse everything except for the "1d" object.

How am I able to parse this?

I'm using a decodable struct and a JSONDecoder/URLSession.

```
[
  {
    "id": "BTC",
    "currency": "BTC",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "price": "23534.92820166",
    "1d": {
      "volume": "35998036640.38",
      "price_change": "533.60149906",
      "price_change_pct": "0.0232",
      "volume_change": "-15387650809.09",
      "volume_change_pct": "-0.2995",
      "market_cap_change": "9934352701.55",
      "market_cap_change_pct": "0.0232"
    }
  }
]
```

TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

It's just an inner struct. As for the name, simply use the CodingKeys. Merely as a proof of concept, pretend that `"1d"` and `"volume"` are the only keys we're interested in:

```
struct Outer : Decodable {
    let the1d: Inner
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the1d = "1d"
    }
}
struct Inner : Decodable {
    let volume: String
}
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Outer].self, from: d)
```

You can take it from there.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
I've been stuck on this for a couple days now.